# Fetching large amount of data from MySQL. Inserting it into Redis Cache. Unable to increase PHP memory limit

Tags: php, mysql, redis, large-data

I have to extract 800 000 rows (it's dev environment, in real it could be 1, even 1.5 mln rows). The **second step** is to insert that stuff as serialized data into Redis cache.

My problems are:

1. Allowed memory size of X bytes is exhausted, but... the key is that I **can't** change it.
2. I figure it out that I can fetching data part by part from MySQL DB. But then **second step** is problematic. So far I used to storing data in Redis as String type (serialized php array of arrays with MySQL data). As yet I don't know how append properly each one part of fetched data. (getting serialized data, unserializing it, then appending new part of data, and serializing it again is... stupid).

Have You any experience with large data operations? I have no idea how to handle it.

Please? :)

Best regards.

Comment: Let me see if I understood. Are you trying to load 800k rows from a db in the server's ram?

Comment: @osnapitzkindle To be clear: I'm trying to manage 800k rows. It does'nt has to be loaded as one bunch. The process is: someone putting data into mysql. I have to place it into redis. Someone else getting data from Redis and doing something...

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would put the content you generate in file as a redis SET command, then execute the file with redis-cli --pipe, read in the following link how your redis mess insertion data file should look like:

[redis mess insertion](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert)

```
<?php
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data['data'] = $line['somekey']; // here generate the desired data
  $data['key'] = 'thekey'; // make the data key
  $redisCommnand = 'SET '.$data['key'].' '.$data['data']; // here you create the redis insert command line someDataKey
  file_put_contents('/tmp/data.txt', $redisCommand, FILE_APPEND);// appending the command to redis command file
}


// exec command to run the file
exec('cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe');
// consider removing the data.txt file
// unlink('/tmp/data.txt');
```